How call two api and show in two difrent flatlist
how to display json data from different apis on each FlatList. here there is a flatlist of flatlists in the HeaderComponent and the other FlatList, because currently it displays the same data in the two FlatLists
'  function BeritaTerkini (){   const \[isLoading, setLoading\] = useState(true);   const \[data, setData\] = useState(\[\]);   const \[data2, setData2\] = useState(\[\]);      const getTerkini = async () =\> {      try {       const response = await fetch('https://mpcms.merahputih.com/api/post?page=1&rpp=20');       const json = await response.json();       setData(json.data);     } catch (error) {       console.error(error);     } finally {       setLoading(false);     }   }          const getHeadline = async () =\> {     try {      const response = await fetch('https://mpcms.merahputih.com/api/post?page=1&rpp=1');      const json = await response.json();      setData(json.data);        } catch (error) {      console.error(error);    } finally {     //  setLoading(false);    }  }      useEffect(() =\> {     getHeadline();     getTerkini();     }, \[\]);     const HeaderComponent = () =\> (   \<View\>           \<FlatList         data={isLoading ? \[\] : data}           keyExtractor={({ id }, index) =\> id}         renderItem={({ item }) =\> (           \<View  style={{padding:15,backgroundColor:"#eeeeee",flex:1, width:'100%'}}\>            \<Image style={styles.imageThumnail} source={require('../assets/coba.jpg')} /\>          \<Text  style={{ lineHeight:24, fontWeight:'600', width:'90%',color: '#fff', bottom: 40, alignSelf: 'center', fontSize:18, position: 'absolute',}}\>           SuperCel Rilis Trailer Squad Buster Bertabur Bintang          \</Text\>       \</View\>           )}         ListEmptyComponent={() =\> isLoading && \<ActivityIndicator /\>}       /\>                 \<View style={{paddingLeft:25,paddingRight:25,paddingTop:20,paddingBottom:20, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}\>         \<Text  style={{ lineHeight:24, fontWeight:'600', width:'90%',color: '#000',   fontSize:18, }}\>           Terkini         \</Text\>       \</View\>   \</View\>                  );          return (     \<View stle={{flex:1, width:'100%'}}\>       \<FlatList         data={isLoading ? \[\] : data}         ListHeaderComponent={HeaderComponent}         keyExtractor={({ id }, index) =\> id}         renderItem={({ item }) =\> (         \<View style={{backgroundColor:'#fff',paddingLeft:25,paddingRight:25}}\>           \<View style={styles.boxArtikel}\>               \<View style={{flexDirection: 'column',width:'40%',height:125,backgroundColor:'#fff'}}\>                   \<Image style={styles.imageArtikelLeft} source={{uri:  item.cover }} /\>               \</View\>               \<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', width:'56%',height:150,backgroundColor:'#fff',paddingLeft:12}}\>                    \<Text  style={{ lineHeight:24,color: 'black',fontSize:16, fontWeight:'600'}}\> {item.title}\</Text\>                \</View\>          \</View\>         \</View\>           )}         ListEmptyComponent={() =\> isLoading && \<ActivityIndicator /\>}       /\>     \</View\>   );    }'
